# Need help identifying some sort of "wire"

Tags: wire, android

I just disassembled my Android Galaxy S in attempt to create something like the iPhones physical sound on\off switch. This is how the unplugged speaker looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HfDq.png]

Until now I have learned the speaker is connected directly to the phone like shown in this picture (The bump in the green zone indicates the wire that's popping out of the speaker. that goes right into the blue "receiver").
What I want to do is "plant" a micro-switch between the phone and the speaker.

[image: http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/6026/whatx.png]

To do so, I need to find out the type of connection of the speaker shown in the first picture, and then get:

- A few wires of this sort.
- A microswitch that goes with it, or some kind of adapter to transfer the wires' signal to and from thicker wires. that way I can plug those wires to a microswitch and then back to the speaker.

As you can see I'm quite a noob in this area, but I'd **really** appreciate any help given. To sum up, my questions are:

- What kind of wire is this?
- Where can I get more of this type?
- Where can I get a microswitch to fit with it, or maybe, like mentioned before, somekind of adapter from and to thicker wires?

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be something like [FFC/FPC](http://www.avx.com/docs/catalogs/ffchist.pdf) cable, which is often used nowadays for PCB connectivity.
It's not the easiest stuff to hack being very delicate. Some is made a bit tougher and intended for e.g. hot bar soldering but I think not the type shown in the photo.

Is it flexible?

You *may* be able to make a connector/switch from a couple of bits pf PCB, depending on the tools available to you. I have etched an connector a few times for soldering display FPC connectors to, but it's not the easiest and this is a bit different anyway as mentioned above. You want something that clamps onto the contacts.

For more of the cable, look on Digikey/Farnell/Mouser/RS etc, for FPC and FFC cable (and connectors, and similar speakers (look at datasheets and they will usually say what connector to use). You may find something you can hack into what you need, or maybe even some ready rolled switch with the required connections (though I am not aware of any, will update if I find something)

I do think this will be very difficult to accomplish, but it's always fun to try :-)

The pitch (space between contacts) looks pretty small - what is it roughly? (hold a ruler with mm markings beside to judge)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering :) I measured the space between each contact and it seems to be no more that .5mm! The whole width of the band is 2mm. I looked for an FFC/FPC cable in Digikey, and what I found looked like they had "solid pins". What I have here is something I'd describe as a "band" that goes out from the speaker and into the input on the phone. I will keep looking in the other sites you mentioned. perhaps there is some site where we can get the prints of the speaker?

Comment: @Itamar - Looking closer, I'm not so sure what you might call it exactly, though it looks like that "family". I think this is more of a jack/plug than a "cable", so checking the phone speaker datasheets recommendations is probably a good idea.

Comment: I think you were right, this is not going to be simple. But I enjoy challenges every once in a while. I'm writing an email to EM-Tech right now, hope I get an answer soon.

Comment: Good idea, typing the part number into Google may bring something up, afraid I can't find much on Mouser etc (didn't help that I misread microphone to start with :-) ) I have always used the PCB mount speakers, but I think that is probably a custom speaker/amp module of some sort.

Comment: Unfortunately, typing the part number in Google mostly results in threads about other Android phones. I guess I will wait for an answer from EMT for now. :)

Comment: Turns out it's the wrong EM-Tech, and I can't find the email address of the EM-Tech I need. but I did find [this](http://www.wdtrade.com/showroom/product/7839/EMTECH.aspx) page, which has a few more details about the speaker. do you see any important detail in it?

Comment: oh, and only now I see you asked if the band is flexible: it is very so.

Comment: Nope, I can't see anything useful either. It seems it is a amp/speaker module as mentioned. Often phone parts will be very difficult to obtain any information about, being such a competitive mass market.